# Get root route depending on dev and prod environment

Tags: html, path, wamp, development-environment

I would like to call script and css from site root.

- I have a dev environment using wamp so my route is `localhost/mysite/js/script.js`.
- My prod environment will be `mysite/js/script.js`.

I would like to call script from root, **what should be the route if I'm not in the root folder and don't want to use `../`?**

The reason for that is I imagine a much more complex arborescence and I want to avoid excessive `../../../../[...]` and I'm wondering if there is something for this.

Let's say I've a page in `pages/contact.html` and I want to call `scripts/contact.js`

- If I call `scripts/contact.js` : 404 because I'm in the `pages` folder.
- If I call `/scripts/contact.js` : It will work in `mysite.com` but won't in local because I need to call `/mysite/scripts/contact.js`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I found the easiest way is to create a local webserver so that you can use `/` everywhere. Otherwise `../` will take a lot more time to get right than just setting up a development server locally. Look at [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @peter-krebs mentioned, the cleanest solution would be to spin up an isolated web server to develop this project in. You could use XAMPP as suggested but a containerized approach using Docker might be more flexible.

Alternatively, you can add a `<base href="/mysite/">` tag to the head of all your pages and write all your paths as relative to that directory. You will have to specify **all** of your resource paths (js, css, images, links) using this *relatively-absolute* method though. Meaning you won't be able to directly access relative resources in the same directory anymore.

For example, if `pages/contact.html` needed the file `pages/contact.js` you could not use the path `./contact.js` from within `contact.html`. You would **have to** specify `pages/contact.js` even though those files are in the same directory.

When you move the site to production, just change the base to `<base href="/">` and everything will continue to work as expected. You could even do this in an automated way by adding the following script to your document head.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      let base = document.createElement('base');
      base.href = (document.location.host == 'localhost') ? '/mysite/' : '/';
      document.currentScript.replaceWith(base);
    </script>
    ...
```